# Is KVM support essential for running Google TV emulator?

Tags: google-tv

I have installed Linux with KVM in my machine.But when i gave "kvm-ok" command in the terminal,it showed "Your CPU doesnot support KVM extensions".
When i checked again,came to know CPU doesn't have VT extensions and hence doesn't support KVM.Does it stop me from running my goolge tv emulator? Or do i need to strictly go for CPU with KVM support?

Comment: If this is closed, please suggest where these questions should go.  I am "programming" (or "developing software") for google-tv and think this question is directly on topic.  I would like to know where to find these answers if not on SO.

Answer (score 3):

YES.

> Google TV emulation is not currently supported on Linux workstations
>   that do not have KVM, nor is it currently supported on Windows and
>   Macintosh platforms.

https://code.google.com/tv/android/docs/gtv_emulator.html

Comment: Their statement is not entirely true.  The emulator may run on workstations that do not support KVM, but it will be slow as a dog. I mean really slooooowwww!!